# Data created from empty data.table causes ggplot error ("replacement has 1 row, data has 0")

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I'm trying to plot two continuous variables generated from a linear model with ggplot but I have a strange error that pops-up.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

n <- 4

DT <- data.table()
DT[, x := rnorm(n)]
DT[, z := rep(-.5:+.5, each = n/2)]
DT[, e := rnorm(n, 0.5)]
DT[, y := 1 + 2*x + 3*z + 4*x*z + e]

ggplot(DT, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

When executed, the scripts returns the following error:

```r
> ggplot(DT, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(x, name, value) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

There doesn't seems to be any issue with the generated data:

```r
> DT
            x    z          e          y
1: -0.6264538 -0.5  0.8295078  0.3295078
2:  0.1836433 -0.5 -0.3204684 -0.8204684
3: -0.8356286  0.5  0.9874291  0.1449146
4:  1.5952808  0.5  1.2383247 10.1194479

> str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ x: num  -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595
 $ z: num  -0.5 -0.5 0.5 0.5
 $ e: num  0.83 -0.32 0.987 1.238
 $ y: num  0.33 -0.82 0.145 10.119
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Curiously, the following code works without issues:

```r
DT2 <- data.table(x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n))
ggplot(DT2, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, but my guess is that ggplot doesn't like how my data is being generated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue as of `data.table 1.12.8` : [data.table not compatible with ggplot when it was generated from empty data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4597).

The reason appears to be that the data created from an empty `data.table` "*does not get row names after assignment.*"

```
rownames(DT)
# character(0)
```

"*We can manually work around this by setting the [row names] attribute*":

```
setattr(DT, "row.names", seq.int(n))
rownames(DT) 
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

ggplot(DT, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
# works!
```

Another work around suggested by the OP in the issue, is to convert to `data.frame` (`setDF`) (and then possibly also convert it back to `data.table`).